# How can I rewrite the getter and setter in Object/Function/Class

Tags: javascript

##### I Want Some Code Like This:

*`anyKey` means any key*

```js
const cache = {
  set [anyKey](value) {
    localStorage.setItem(`prefix_${anyKey}`, value)
  },

  get [anyKey]() {
    return localStorage.getItem(`prefix_${anyKey}`);
  }
}
```

#### Then I Want It Works Like:

```js
// if this
cache.a = 'someVal'

// I want this
localStorage.setItem('prefix_a', 'someVal')

// if this
console.log(cache.a)

// I want this... 
// output 'someVal'
console.log(localStorage.getItem('prefix_a'));
```

I do not know how to write it... help me, plz.

Comment: please clarify your question. what have you tried so far and why didn't it work? can you give a better description of your expected result?

Comment: I would use a proxy for this

Comment: Use a getter and a setter for the `a` property

Comment: The easiest way would be to wrap your `cache` into [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) along with local storage.

Below code does not work here, because of

```text
Uncaught SecurityError:
Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.
```

```js
const
    cache = new Proxy(
        {},
        {
            get(_, prop) {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(prop));
            },
            set(_, prop, value) {
                localStorage.setItem(prop, JSON.stringify(value));
                return true;
            }
        }
    );

cache.a = 1;
console.log(cache.a);

cache.b = 'some value';
console.log(cache.b);
```

Comment: What if I want  `cache.b = 1`? I do not want write `set b(value)...` again.
I want it setItem or getItem automatic

Comment: @Xavier you don't have to. That's how **Proxy** works.

Comment: @Xavier  Proxy's `get` and `set` methods catches and handles all the keys.

Comment: @Jaood_xD, the comment of *Xavier* is ment to the previous edit, not the actual one.

Comment: @NinaScholz oh, my bad. I thought that *Xavier* didn't get pros of your solution